# Heroku App crashed with no reason

Tags: heroku

I'm receiving this arror on each new app that I created. Curiosly, The way I created the applications that break is exactly the same as I used with applications that are working correctly.

It could be related to the number of applications that I'm using on heroku?

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=akasha-me.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=2951c325-76c4-4655-8e60-ae63230074b2 fwd="190.151.174.232"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I'm very new to nuxt. So please, if anyone can help me to solve this I will be very grateful,

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If your app’s logging has been set up properly, you should see additional crash information in your logs. If not, you’ll want to adjust the logging level for your application. Since this is ultimately a programming related question, I would also recommend taking this question to Stack Overflow: www.stackoverflow.com